# Datetimpicker disable past times for today, enable for tommorow

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vivpad/7s0a7m3p/7/ 
I am using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ with moment.js

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
<h6>datetimepicker2</h6>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" />
</div>
</div>
```

My JQuery code is as follows

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});

$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  format: 'LT'
});
```

I need following:

- If date selected is todays date, then in timepicker one should not be able to select previous time. Eg if I select todays date and current time is 2:11pm hen one should not be able to select 2:10 or before.
- If Date selected is tomorrows or any date further, then the minimum time available to selection should be 10:00 AM.
- In both the cases Max time available for selection should be 5:00 PM and not above that.
- All previous dates before today should be disabled.

Comment: Please update your question with what you've attempted so far.

Comment: a little help from moment.js?

Comment: Most of the answers to your 4 questions are in the docs in the link you posted. http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<br/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h6>Datetimepicker</h6>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {     
            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ 
             format : 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            minDate: moment().add(1, 'h'),enabledHours: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,17]
                });

        });
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/5u694sat/5/)

Answer (score 3):

you could use something like this --

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    'format': 'd/m/Y H:i',
    'minDate': -0,
    'closeOnDateSelect' : true,
    'validateOnBlur' : true,
    'minDateTime': new Date()
});
```